# Expanding a circular ArrayDeque

Tags: java, arrays, deque, arraydeque

I'm trying to implement my own ArrayDeque, fully aware of the utils.ArrayDeque available. (It's for a school project).
I've created, what seems to be, a working implementation of ArrayDeque.  My issue is trying to create a child of ArrayDeque that grows when it's full instead of throwing exceptions.  When it grows the indices are correct (?), but my array order doesn't make sense.

Heres a link to the project, related code under.
https://github.com/tagptroll1/Oblig1/tree/master/src/Deque

```
//From ResizeableArrayDeque
private void growArray(){
    int newCapacity = deque.length * 2;
    if (newCapacity >= MAX_CAPACITY){
        throw new DequeFullException("Tried to expand deque past MAX Capacity");
    }
    //deque = Arrays.copyOf(deque, newCapacity);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] tempDeque = (E[]) new Object[newCapacity];
    for (int i = deque.length; i > 0; i--){
        if (!isArrayEmpty()){
            tempDeque[i] = pullLast();
        } else {
            throw new DequeEmptyException("Tried to pull element from empty deque");
        }
    }
    deque = tempDeque;
    topIndex = 0;
    botIndex = numberOfEntries;
}

@Override
public void addFirst(E elem){
    if (isArrayFull()){
        growArray();
    }
    deque[topIndex = dec(topIndex, deque.length)] = elem;
    numberOfEntries ++;
}

@Override
public void addLast(E elem){
    if (isArrayFull()){
        growArray();
    }
    deque[botIndex] = elem;
    numberOfEntries ++;
    botIndex = inc(botIndex, deque.length);
}

// From ArrayDeque
protected static int inc(int i, int modulus) {
    if (++i >= modulus) {
        i = 0;
    }
    return i;
}


protected static int dec(int i, int modulus) {
    if (--i < 0) {
        i = modulus - 1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I do not see how to copy the old array over to the new bigger one, as the ordering doesn't work out with newer elements added afterward.  Heres a test print of the array:

```
 Adding [a, b, c, d] to deques bottom
Adding: 0 arrayIndex to 1. tail-index, element: a
[a] [null] [4] [3] [2] [1] 
Adding: 1 arrayIndex to 2. tail-index, element: b
[a] [b] [4] [3] [2] [1] 
Adding: 2 arrayIndex to 1. tail-index, element: c
[c] [4] [3] [2] [1] [a] [b] [null] [null] [null] [null] [null] 
Adding: 3 arrayIndex to 2. tail-index, element: d
[c] [d] [3] [2] [1] [a] [b] [null] [null] [null] [null] [null] 
Current Tail index is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in me forgetting to save `numberOfEntries` before pulling from the first array since that variable would be 0 when I set the index afterward.  Problem solved by creating a temp int to hold it until the transfer was completed